# How to "add" the proxy section to configure a registry as a pull-through cache?

Tags: caching, docker, docker-registry, docker-machine

I want to configure a local pull-through registry cache, and following this document: 
https://github.com/docker/distribution/blob/master/docs/mirror.md#configuring-the-cache

It says I need to add such a section:

```
proxy:
  remoteurl: https://registry-1.docker.io
  username: [username]
  password: [password]
```

I have several questions:

1. What's the `https://registry-1.docker.io`? Is it a public registry which is the same as the offical docker registry?
2. What's the correct url if I want to the cache to connect to the offical registry?
3. How to "add" this section?

About "how to add this section", this document https://docs.docker.com/registry/configuration/ says two ways:

1. pass `-e REGISTRY_PROXY_REMOTEURL=http://???` to **override** a configuration
2. provide a `config.yml` to override the default **completely**

It seems the two approaches don't suit it, I need a way to "add", how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Pass `-e "REGISTRY_PROXY_REMOTEURL=https://registry-1.docker.io"` in the docker run command line. It should work. I have the same questions as you regarding config.yml, etc .. I tried overriding the config.yml but I figured out it should be populated with lots of default values, otherwise it will not work.